# Singular Del Pezzo of degree 2

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, singularity-theory, algebraic-surfaces

Throughout, singular Del Pezzo means a surface with only isolated singularities and ample anti-canonical divisor.

Suppose $X$ is a singular Del Pezzo of degree 2 over a field $k$ where $\text{char}(k)\neq 2$. Assume $X$ has one singular point. Is it possible to project from this singular point? If so what is the image of this projection?

Comment: That depends on what do you mean. If you have a del Pezzo of higher degree, "projecting from a point" usually means just blowing up this point. And of course, you can blowup a singular point on a del Pezzo surface of degree 2.

Comment: @Sasha No I don’t want to blow up. For example on a cubic surface $X:x_{0}f_{2}+f_{3}$ with a singular point at $(x_{0},\dotsc,x_{3})=(1,0,0,0)$ one can “project from the singular point” by constructing a map to $\mathbb{P}^{2}$ by sending $(x_{0},\dotsc,x_{3})\mapsto (x_{1},x_{2},x_{3})$.

Comment: But this map is well-defined only on the blow-up of the singular point.

Comment: @HU: In the cubic surface example, the blowup of a singular point is a weak del Pezzo surface that has a natural morphism to $\mathbb{P}^2$ (and this morphism itself is the blowup of 6 points lying on a conic). In the degree 2 case the blowup of the singular point is also a weak del Pezzo, so what do you want to understand about it?

Comment: @Sasha For the singular cubic case the rational map above will map $X$ birationally into a plane. I was wondering if one could do something similar for Del pezzos of degree 2?

Comment: @HU: Any weak del Pezzo surface of degree $2$ is a blowup (in many different ways) of a plane in 7 points in almost general position.

Comment: @Sasha over an algebraically closed field it is but not over a general field

Comment: @HU: Ah, OK, I missed that point. In this case, the linear system $|-K_{\tilde{X}} -E|$ (where $\tilde{X}$ is the blowup, $K_{\tilde{X}}$ is its canonical class, and $E$ is exceptional divisor) provides $\tilde{X}$ with a structure of a conic bundle over $\mathbb{P}^1$.